Why doesn't kubernetes enforce memory limits using OOMKill of the process that started a container
Kubernetes uses linux cgroups to enforce memory limits defined for a pod container.
As this container process forks children and then the memory limit is exceeded, it is not guaranteed that linux actually kills the process that started the container.
If another process (a process forked by the main container process) is killed, kubernetes doesn't notice and the cause of the error might not be detected easily. The behavior of the surviving parent process might be unpredictable, no OOMKill event is generated.
Why doesn't kubernetes / linux try to actually kill the container process if the memory limit is exceeded? In this case the OOMKill would be detected by kubernetes.
